# Spring Boot uses /tmp/spring.log file during testing

Tags: logging, spring-boot, logback

One of my Spring Boot applications makes problems during its Maven *test* phase.

Both during testing and "regular" application runtime, the Spring Boot application uses a logback configuration file very similar to [`src/main/resources/logback-spring.xml`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v1.3.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-logback/src/main/resources/logback-spring.xml). This configuration file (transitively) includes the logback configuration files [`base.xml`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v1.3.1.RELEASE/spring-boot/src/main/resources/org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml) and [`file-appender.xml`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v1.3.1.RELEASE/spring-boot/src/main/resources/org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/file-appender.xml). These configuration files set a *logback property* `LOG_FILE=/tmp/spring.log`.

I guess it is best practice that file `/tmp/server.log` is owned by user and group `${MY_SPRING_BOOT_APPLICATION}`.

Jenkins runs as user `jenkins`. `jenkins` does not have write permissions for `/tmp/server.log`. Therefore the JUnit tests fail when executed by Jenkins.

- What is the best way to configure logging so that it works well during a Jenkins *build-with-tests* **and** so that it sets up *daily rolling logging* when leveraging [Spring Boot's *SysV init.d* service functionality](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/deployment-install.html) (which puts logs into `/var/log/`)?
- Will file `/tmp/spring.log` be modified (and therefore be broken) concurrently if there are two or more Spring Boot applications running at the same time?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In my Spring Boot application, I have added `<property name="LOG_TEMP" value="./logs"/>` to `src/test/resources/logback-test.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<configuration scan="true">
    <property name="LOG_TEMP" value="./logs"/>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml"/>

    <logger name="com.example" level="INFO"/>


    <root level="WARN">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
    </root>

</configuration>
```

This way, during Maven testing, a separate logging file will be created in the current (testing) working directory.

[Props to *welcor* for helping out](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/5124).

Comment: Make sure you put the property override before the <include > property, as demonstrated here.

Answer (score 2):

We were experiencing an issue where running multiple Spring Boot modules on the same server was causing multiple processes to try to write to `/tmp/spring.log`. We solved this by updating `logback-spring.xml` to include `${PID}` in the log name:

```
<property name="LOG_FILE" value="${LOG_FILE:-${LOG_PATH:-${LOG_TEMP:-${java.io.tmpdir:-/tmp}}}/spring.log}"/>
```

to

```
<property name="LOG_FILE" value="${LOG_FILE:-${LOG_PATH:-${LOG_TEMP:-${java.io.tmpdir:-/tmp}}}/spring-${PID}.log}"/>
```

Related Spring docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.x/reference/html/howto-logging.html#howto-configure-logback-for-logging

Answer (score 0):

If the permissions are insufficient, you can modify them using the chmod command:

```
 chmod +r /tmp/spring.log
```