# Spring boot spring.log under tmp

Tags: java, spring-boot, logging

I have gone through [Spring Boot uses /tmp/spring.log file during testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38081145/spring-boot-uses-tmp-spring-log-file-during-testing)

But that didnt help. I have a logback.xml in my spring boot application and when i start it up it creates a log in var/tmp/spring.log. Now this cant work on client site. Is there a way to configure it to not create it my log back is already logging the console in the log file i have defined in my appender. I didnt even know this was happening. and this spring.log is used with a Rolling file appender which means that it will keep on creating logs each day.

I removed:

```
<!--include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml"/-->
```

from my logback.xml but it still didnt stop it from accessing the file or creating it

any help will be appreciated

EDIT: my logback.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<configuration scan="true">
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml"/>

    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>logs/fix.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
            <maxHistory>90</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <encoder>
            <charset>utf-8</charset>
            <Pattern>%d %-5level [%thread] %logger{0}: %msg%n</Pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="ASYNC" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.AsyncAppender">
        <queueSize>512</queueSize>
        <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
    </appender>





<logger name="com.comp.myapp" level="INFO"/>


<contextListener class="ch.qos.logback.classic.jul.LevelChangePropagator">
    <resetJUL>true</resetJUL>
</contextListener>

<root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    <!--<appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>-->
</root>
```

The problem that arises from this is that if i deployed the same application twice even with the same user. both applications are writing to the same file which makes no sense. If i had another spring boot application also deployed on the same machine they will write to the same spring.log in tmp folder. I dont understand whats the reason behind creating a "sneaky" log ( i would call it sneaky)

Comment: Could you add you logback.xml?

Answer (score 8):

replace

```
<include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml"/>
```

with

```
<include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml" />
```

Links for details:-

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/12538

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot/src/main/resources/org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot/src/main/resources/org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml

Answer (score 7):

Adding

```
<include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml" />
```

is indeed important, but what you ultimately want is all the features you'd get WITHOUT saving logs to `tmp`. If you look at `<include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml" />` you will find the following:

```
<included>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml" />
    <property name="LOG_FILE" value="${LOG_FILE:-${LOG_PATH:-${LOG_TEMP:-${java.io.tmpdir:-/tmp}}}/spring.log}"/>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/console-appender.xml" />
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/file-appender.xml" />
    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </root>
</included>
```

Therefore, you want to replace `<include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml" />` with the following:

```
<include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml" />
<include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/console-appender.xml" />
<include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/file-appender.xml" />
<root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
</root>
```

This way, you can still see logs in your IDE as you would if you used the base xml.